# Prime division proof

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, prime-factorization

Prove $x=y$ while $x$ and $y$ are positive integers and $1+x+y$ is a prime divisor of $-1 + 4(x*y)$.

This is a homework, but I don't want a full solution - just some tips to get started.

Comment: First of all note that : 
$x \equiv y \mod 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=1+x+y$, and rewrite $-1+4xy$ in terms of $x$ and $p$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using this tip i came to:
$-1 + 4xy = 4px - (2x+1)^2$
and as p divides  $-1 + 4xy$ **and** $4px$ it also must divide $(2x+1)^2$ and particularly $2x+1$ (as it's prime). $2x+1≡0 mod p$ so $2x+1≡p=x+y+1 mod p$ thus $x≡y mod p$ and $x-y≡0 mod p$. As $x-y < x < x+y+1$ and $x+y+1$ divides $x-y$ then $x-y$ must be equal to $0$.
What do you think about this solution?

Comment: Yes, I think that's right